@capacitor/barcode-scanner barcode scanner crash when starting the scan function
Hello i'm facing this issue where when the scan is called it crash:
this is the code
import {
  CapacitorBarcodeScanner,
  CapacitorBarcodeScannerAndroidScanningLibrary,
  CapacitorBarcodeScannerCameraDirection,
  CapacitorBarcodeScannerScanOrientation,
  CapacitorBarcodeScannerTypeHint,
} from "@capacitor/barcode-scanner";
import { Camera } from "@capacitor/camera";


 const checkCameraPermission = async () => {
      try {
        const status = await Camera.requestPermissions();
        console.log("Camera permission status:", JSON.stringify(status));
        if (status.camera !== "granted") {
          alert("Camera permission is required to scan QR codes.");
          return false;
        }
        return true;
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error requesting camera permission:", error);
        alert("Error requesting permission. Please try again.");
        return false;
      }
    };

    const startScanner = async () => {
      const hasPermission = await checkCameraPermission();
      if (!hasPermission) return;
      console.log(JSON.stringify(hasPermission));

      try {
        const scanResult = await CapacitorBarcodeScanner.scanBarcode({
          hint: CapacitorBarcodeScannerTypeHint.ALL,
          cameraDirection: CapacitorBarcodeScannerCameraDirection.BACK,
          scanOrientation: CapacitorBarcodeScannerScanOrientation.PORTRAIT,
          android: {
            scanningLibrary:
              CapacitorBarcodeScannerAndroidScanningLibrary.ZXING,
          },
        });

        console.log("Scan result:", JSON.stringify(scanResult));

        if (scanResult.hasContent) {
          alert(`QR Code Content: ${scanResult.content}`);
        } else {
          alert("No QR code detected.");
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error during scan:", error);
        alert("An error occurred while scanning. Please try again.");
      }
    };

there is no even error showing in logcat so im confuse whats happening. please give suggestion or advice.
when the permission log is true
after that it crashes
